# Animation for UINavigationBar.setBackgroundImage not working properly

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, uiviewanimation

I need to change the background image of the `navBar` in my view at some point,

```
let animation = CATransition()
override func viewDidLoad() {
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade
    animation.duration = 0.5
}
```

at `scrollViewDidScroll()` func I should change the `backgroundImage`

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll() {
    if someCondition {
        showNavigationBar()
    } else {
        hideNavigationBar()
    }
}

func showNavigationBar() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { 
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> the problem is happening here the animation in this block didn't occur.However, while debugging the complier run this instruction, but there's no animation . :(

```
func hideNavigationBar() {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So what's the problem, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make this happen, I just added one line to hideNavigationBar(), clearly that after changing `navBar` background Image the animation gone. So all I need to re-add it ':)

```
func hideNavigationBar() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```